# Can flush DNS command resolve internet speeds?

Tags: macos, networking, command-line, dns

Was assisting a user that had been downloading 8 movies from iTunes. Her speed was sitting at .06 mbps down with ethernet. Restart and power cycle got her up to 2.36 mbps down. 
0% packet loss.

I might be wrong, but it seems like flushing the DNS in the past has helped to resolve email issues after user has sent large files.

Am I wrong in assuming that flushing DNS could help resolve speeds issues?

Comment: You are indeed wrong.  What is more likely there were other connections or programs using the limited bandwidth already running.  Flushng the DNS would not increase/decrease internet speeds.

Comment: I could see my internet speed become suddenly instantaneous after flush dns on mac. I never expected this. I am under corporate VPN, so can that be a caching a lot of things?

Answer (score 2):

DNS is one of *many* factors when it comes to Internet speed. It's possible that flushing DNS can have some improvement, but it won't be much. If anything, it'll clear out obsolete entries if it hasn't been done in a while and caching is interfering with something, but clearing the cache can actually lower overall speeds (slightly) by requiring new DNS lookups for every resource.

Answer (score 0):

I found, despite having a very fast i7 PC with SSD drives, it would sometimes take almost a minute after a start up before I could open my homepage. The browser would start up but would display a white screen for a while. After the home page was finally displayed, internet was fast and following websites would display instantly. I had no malware or spyware.

Then I flushed my DNS and now when I boot up my PC and click my browser, the website immediately shows up. So it *may* be possible a full DNS cache slows down your initial connection speed.

Comment: I was shocked to see that responses became instant on my Mac after flushing DNS. Landed on this question to find out whether it was flush DNS command or something else that did the trick.